# iOS and watchkit: How to resolve this issues? Xcode 7 beta with iOS 9 and watch OS 2

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

```
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

Not running swift-stdlib-tool: EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT is enabled, but the product type 'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2' is not a wrapper type.

Unable to run command 'PBXCp VimoHeartRate\ WatchKit\ App\ Extension.appex' - this target might include its own product.
```

While trying to run a watch app, I got the above. Any know how to resolve this?

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm running into the same issue now.